# Unable to install MySql in 22.04 - showing "package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate"

Tags: apt, server, mysql

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please enable "universe".  See amongst others https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127524/e-package-mysql-server-has-no-installation-candidate or https://askubuntu.com/questions/763240/is-it-possible-to-install-mysql-5-5-or-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/855615/how-to-install-mysql-server-5-5-on-ubuntu16-04

Answer (score 0):

You can install mariadb-server, it's a fork of mysql and so the operation is basically the same, including the command to execute queries in the database.